# Integration Problem Help Please

Tags: calculus

Please give hint how to solve integral 
$$ \int \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^4 + 2x^2y^2 + y^4}dx.$$

I have tried substitution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

Assuming $y$ to be independent of $x$

As $x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4=(x^2+y^2)^2$

using [Trigonometric substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution), set $x=y\tan\theta\implies dx=y\sec^2\theta\ d\theta $

Also observe that $x^2-y^2=(x^2+y^2)-2y^2$

Comment: The answer should be $-\dfrac{x}{x^2+y^2}+C$.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar, yes another way is $$\frac yx=v$$